# log all requests in mongodb

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a nodejs-express-mongoose application and I want to set logging system up.
I know about connect.logger() middleware but I want to log into MongoDB database.

Can I achieve that by using overriding connect.logger() middleware of are some express plugins for my purposes?

Comment: If you already have `logger` in place and configured, it seems that you can pass it your own output buffer where you can intercept log lines and store them in mongo. I don't think this comment benefits a full answer, but might point you in the (possibly) right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mongoose has a `debug` option that logs all collection method invocations (update, insert, find, ensureIndex, etc) with `console.error`. you may also override it with your own custom function:

```
mongoose.set('debug', true) // for logging with console.error
mongoose.set('debug', yourFunction) // to handle it yourself
```

Comment: Thank you aaron for the reply, I was confused by the 'debug' word can I use your recipe in production?

Comment: i don't recommend using the default behavior of debug in production b/c it includes a ton of formatting. probably override it with your own function and handle it how you desire.